# How can this class with another class collection inside it be better written/designed and what is wrong with this current implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

```
class A
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public List<B> B { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
 class B
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }

    public static List<B> CreateB(int [] parameter, string str, int number)
    {
        var bList = new List<B>();

        foreach (var item in parameter)
        {
            var b = new B();
            b.MyProperty = number;
            b.SetProperty1(str);

            bList.Add(b);
        }
        return bList;
    }

    private void SetProperty1(string s)
    {
        //logic here applied to 's'
        this.MyProperty1 = s;
    }
}
```

---

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int id = 123;
        int [] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

        var A = DataBase.GetListOfA(id);
        UpdateB(A, array);
    }

    public static void UpdateB(List<A> data, int[] numbers)
    {
        var array = new int[] {5,10,15};
        var str = "hi";
        var number = 1;

        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            if(item.B == null || item.B.Count == 0)
            {
                item.B = new List<B>();
                item.B = B.CreateB(array, str, number);
            }
            else
            {
                //B.UpdateB(/*parameters here*/);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Class B is directly related to A but cannot be inside A because the amount of class B's per A is dynamic and varies.

I'm not sure how to ask for help regarding this but should class B not be creating a list of itself using a static method?

Should B be separated from A if possible or could I simply create B inside a method that fills the property inside A.

For instance a Create A method that takes some parameters to set every property in A thereby also creating B in said method?

Comment: A and B don't give so much context. I am wondering if it would help if you would explain what kind of problem you are trying to solve with having A and B around. Meaning: this looks like one of these examples that are very clear; but that, in essence, say nothing about the real problem you are struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> create B inside a method that fills the property inside A.
>
> For instance a Create A method that takes some parameters to set every property in A thereby also creating B in said method

That is what I would do.  This is the approach more closely aligned with the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  `B` doesn't need to know that it is one item in an array, it just needs to represent a `B` object.  `A` knows that it contains a list of `B`s so it should manage that list.

Comment: Thanks Jaquez that was what I have been thinking about to approach this problem. I may go with it.

Answer (score 1):

I am short on time, so I'll provide a suggestion regarding this one part of your question: "I'm not sure how to ask for help regarding this but should class B not be creating a list of itself using a static method?"

I would make CreateB return only a single B.  If you have a bunch of parameters that you need to make into B's (for example, an array of ints), then I would use LINQ like this:

```
List<B> theBees = parameter.Select(param => B.CreateB(param, str, number)).ToList();
```

Vladmir Khorikov talks about constructors in his excellent Pluralsight course on functional programming in C#.  [Check out the Create method Vladmir defines on this Email class](https://github.com/vkhorikov/FuntionalPrinciplesCsharp/blob/master/New/CustomerManagement.Logic/Model/Email.cs).  I think it's a super clean way to handle object creation and validation.

Comment: Thanks Jordan I'll look into it.